# Integrate SpagoBi in .net

Tags: c#, .net, spagobi

I want to integrate a .net M.V.C application with SpagoBI.
I have searched in the spago bi forum didn't find any solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try already? Show us some code of what you tried. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I didn't try it yet I want to know if i can do that. I Just have my mvc application which has a dashboard for showing data. I want to use charts for data visualization that's why i need spago bi integration.